# Google Earth Plugin not exact coordinates

Tags: google-earth-plugin

I've got quite strange google earth plugin behaviour. I get the camera position from the plugin to create some KML with coordinates, then I store it in database. When I reload the page, then it reads the kml, inserts it inside some other string - as a result I've got a string with whole kml document inside my javascript code. Then I load it into the plugin. Usually everything works, however after loading I see two things:

- The coordinates returned by the API are not the same I have in the kml I'm loading
- The camera position is sometimes moved a little bit, which causes errors like: I've got a camera inside a building, and after a couple of page refreshing, the camera suddenly is outside the building.

Do you have any hints how this could be fixed?

Example:

I've created a document, and inserted this camera tag inside:

```
<Camera>
  <gx:ViewerOptions><gx:option name='streetview'></gx:option></gx:ViewerOptions>
  <longitude>2.1201209999999993</longitude>
  <latitude>48.80452499999986</latitude>
  <altitude>2.4999999991174264</altitude>
  <heading>22.795249807940547</heading>
  <tilt>82.25987544961218</tilt>
  <altitudeMode>relativeToGround</altitudeMode>
</Camera>
```

Then I loaded it into the plugin, and asked to fly there. When it stopeed flying, I got the coordinates using copyAsCamera() and the latitude was changed to `48.8044078508718`.

The difference is not huge, just `0.000117149` but as a result it is showing a totally different place (a different room in the palace.

I'm trying to get exactly the same place, as written in the coordinates.

Comment: You would need to show your actual code or at least and example of the issue. It is impossible to say without seeing.

Comment: No, that is not an example. You should follow this guide when asking for help with code - http://sscce.org/

Comment: I don't think I'm going to place here the whole application code. So once again: I load e.g. this kml https://gist.github.com/szymong/45bf4b1fc4fec78ef7e6 when plugin stops flying, the camera is at this place, or another. I have no idea why it doesn't fly to the same place all the time. What's more, when I get the viewchangeend event and read the camera position with `ge.getView().copyAsCamera(ge.ALTITUDE_RELATIVE_TO_GROUND).getLongitude()` then I get a little bit different numbers than in the original KML.

Comment: And yes, I've also cut the coordinates to 6 decimal places - it behaves the same.

Comment: If you can't or won't show a _simple example_ of the problem then it is impossible to say what is happening. It could be any number of reasons.

Comment: OK, so here is some example what is going on. https://gist.github.com/szymong/064f96cc1fb5d6944996 This loads a doucument with camera tag to google earth plugin and flies there. Below the plugin there are two fields, one with the original camera tag, and the second with current coordinates read from the plugin. The problem is that the current coordinates are not the same as requested. Usually tilt is different, but quite often the latitude changes to 48.804408 and it shows totally different place in the building. Another strange thing is that viewchangeend event is sent a couple of times.

Comment: The behaviour is not deterministic. It happens from time to time, I have to refresh the browser sometimes twice, sometimes 20 times to repeat that.

Answer (score 0):

I have rewritten the answer to cover the various points you have made and the example you have provided.

**street view**

The KML data is setting `<gx:ViewerOptions>` to enter street view mode *based on* the camera. The key words being *based on* - a street view is an approximation. Things like the camera `tilt` and `heading` are no longer applicable as they are replaced by a SteeetView POV object. Further to that you can't guarantee that a camera at any given latitude and longitude will actually enter street view at the same given latitude and longitude.

**relativeToGround and terrain data**

Using altitude mode `relativeToGround` can cause the issue you are seeing. This is because the terrain data hasn't always finished streaming when the relatively positioned element (in your case a camera) is added.

To be clear you should use `<altitudeMode>absolute</altitudeMode>` and `ge.ALTITUDE_ABSOLUTE`.

The example you provided uses both `<altitudeMode>relativeToGround</altitudeMode>` and `ge.ALTITUDE_RELATIVE_TO_GROUND`.

You could also try disabling the terrain data by turning off the terrain layer, i.e.

```
ge.getLayerRoot().enableLayerById(ge.LAYER_TERRAIN, false);
```

**multiple viewchangeend events**

The `viewchangeend` event may fire in the middle of a `viewchange`, especially if the plugin pauses for a brief period during the change. Your markup is triggering street view mode which causes this to happen.

You can resolve this by using `setTimeout` to throttle the `viewchangeend` event like so.

```
var timer = null;
google.earth.addEventListener(ge.getView(), 'viewchangeend', function(){
  if(timer){
    clearTimeout(timer);
  }
    timer = setTimeout(eventHandler, 100);
  }
);
```

see: https://developers.google.com/earth/documentation/events#event_listeners

**Tilt discrepancy**

The plugin automatically "swoops" at ground level so that it moves from looking straight down (0 degrees tilt) to straight along the horizon (90 degrees tilt). This is what is causing the discrepancy in the tilt value in the view. You are viewing objects at ground level and so the view is being automatically set - this can't be disabled.

**Storing and outputting KML data**

Take a look through this document, it gives some really good information of storing coordinate data and covers points like the one I mentioned - [A Database Driven Earth App](https://developers.google.com/earth/articles/phpsqlearth).

.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I got those coordinates from google earth plugin using the code from https://developers.google.com/earth/documentation/camera_control. I create kml directly in javascript and store it as text in database. There are no operations on this text, just using e.g. view.getAltitude() for getting the altitude. Then I ask Google Earth Plugin to fly to the coordinates I got from it earlier, and it flies to another place. When I refresh the website, it can even fly to quite new one.

Comment: And comment continuation - as the character limit is too low :) I cannot use the view serialization, as I need to make simple KML, which I use then to load it to external Google Earth (not to plugin).

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I think the first part is the most important for me: "...they are replaced by a SteeetView POV object. Further to that you can't guarantee that a camera at any given latitude and longitude will actually enter street view at the same given latitude and longitude." So it seems that it works like this, and there is nothing I can do to have the camera exactly at the same place each time when in StreetView mode.

Comment: I think it would be possible using the panorama object in v3 of the maps api, it is essentially the same steetview but allows things like custom tile sets and exposes many more members for things like view set up and control layout.

Comment: I'm afraid I cannot use the maps api, in the end the saved position is shown in the Google Earth (not plugin, but standalone program).